# Analogue of capistrano/fabric for common lisp + restas + huchentoot

Tags: deployment, lisp, common-lisp, web-deployment, webdeploy

Does exists any deployment tool for cl like [capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano)(ruby)/[fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html)(python)?

Requirments:

- [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) support;
- simple one-command deploy to server (like `cap deploy`), that `pull` updates from repository;
- support of database ([mysql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)/[postgresql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgresql)) migrations ([schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) changes, loading data, etc.).

Comment: it would be useful if you could add requirements for the deployment-tool, and/or a description of what the tool shall accomplish as not everybody (e.g. myself) is familiar with the named.

Comment: actually, there's no problem in using cap/fab directly with Lisp. What are your specific use-cases, which aren't covered?

Comment: Yeah, fabric may be enough for this, but usage of native tools is prefered by me.